# Connect and Listen on same port from different sockets can't process incoming SYN (MAC OSX)

Tags: c++, macos, sockets, tcp

I have two peers. Peer A(MAC OSX) has two sockets bound on same port. One operating on active mode and one on passive mode. Peer B(any OS) has only one socket acting on Active mode. Peer A starts listening in a separate thread. And after that calls Connect from a different thread. But Peer B is not listening so the connect call of A is failed. Then Peer B call Connect but this connect also fails.

In wireshark I see the SYN leaving B and entering on A's PC. But Accept API call of A doesn't return valid FD which means A is not being able to process the SYN. So no SYN-ACK is also leaving A's PC.

If peer A is any OS (e.g windows,ubuntu, centos) other than MAC than this issue is not reproduced.

**EDIT:**

While creating the socket we set some socket options. They are O_NONBLOCK, TCP_NODELAY, SO_REUSEADDR, SO_LINGER and for OSX, iOS SO_NOSIGPIPE.

**CODE:**

This is the listening part of A.

```
int iAcceptResult = -1;

if (::listen(currentTcpSocket,1)< 0)
{
    Log("Listen error: " + itoa(LastNetworkError());
}   

unsigned int i = 0;
while ((iAcceptResult < 0 )
{
    sleep(80);
    iAcceptResult = Accept(currentTcpSocket);
    if (0 == iAcceptResult)
    {
        //success
        break;
    }       
}
```

This is connecting part for both A and B.

```
int iConnect = Connect(currentTcpSocket, uAddr, uPort);
if (iConnect < 0)
{
    return false;
}
int connectTimeout = 750; //milliseconds
int nWaitResult = UseSelect(currentTcpSocket,connectTimeout);
if (nWaitResult != 0)       
{
    // timeout or error
}
```

Connect , Accept and UseSelect functions

```
int Connect(SOCKET sock, const IpAddress& uAddr, u_int16_t uPort)
{
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    memset((char *)&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = uPort;
    sin.sin_addr = uAddr.addr4;

    return ::connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
}

int Accept(SOCKET m_sock)
{
    sock_accept = ::accept(m_sock, NULL, NULL);
    if (INVALID_SOCKET == sock_accept)
        return -1;   
    return 0;
}

int UseSelect(SOCKET fd, int iTimeoutMs)
{
    fd_set readEvents;
    fd_set writeEvents;
    fd_set exceptEvents;

    FD_ZERO(&writeEvents);
    FD_ZERO(&readEvents);
    FD_ZERO(&exceptEvents);
    FD_SET(fd, &exceptEvents);

    if(true == read)
    {
        FD_SET(fd, &readEvents);
    }
    else
    {
        FD_SET(fd, &writeEvents);
    }

    timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = iTimeoutMs / 1000;
    timeout.tv_usec = (iTimeoutMs % 1000) * 1000;   


    return ::select(fd + 1, &readEvents, NULL, &exceptEvents, &timeout);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the minimal code to repro?

Comment: On the Mac can you try disabling the Firewall in the system settings?

Comment: Firewall was already turned off. As the syn is received by A's wireshark I don't think the firewall is the problem.